# Converting font families w\Fontforge

Tags: conversion, fonts, adobe-photoshop, truetype-fonts

I'm using Fontforge to convert some fonts to Truetype. However, when installed, not all variants of the converted fonts appear in Photoshop; generally only Bold and Italic variants show up. (Usually even regular isn't available.)

After doing some research, I've set the family on all the font variations to be the same, and given each it's own each name, but that didn't help any.

How can I convert fonts so that Photoshop sees them as a family?